# Excel VBA - organise data into struct in a hierachical way

Tags: excel, vba

I have this csv file which I want to organize into a struct. I am measuring some surfaces and under every surface there are sections and under every section there are a number of runs. I want to write a structure code such that each surface with have all the section and runs under it extracted. the structure should look like this. surface(I).section(k).run(m). this is how the data looks like:

```
SURFACE
SECTION
RUN
-0.07764007
0.07762
42
0.07801
-0.07747896
0.07744
-0.07753022
0.07759
-0.07729586
0.07747
-0.07753753
0.07741
-0.07742768
RUN
-0.077435
0.07747
-0.07757416
0.07726
-0.07761077
0.07756
-0.07750092
-57
-0.07712009
0.07771
-0.07769133
0.07769
-0.07713472
0.07733
-0.07726657
0.0774
-0.07731783
0.07743
-0.07754486
0.07752
-0.07755219
0.07745
-0.07723726
SECTION
RUN
-0.07785247
0.07765
-0.07742036
-0.0776
-0.07742036
0.07747
-0.07729586
0.07741
-0.07744966
0.07724
-0.07753753
0.0773
-0.07747896
0.07759
-0.07746429
0.07771
SURFACE
SECTION
RUN
-0.07753753
0.07786
-0.07729586
0.07743
-0.07762542
0.07763
-0.07723726
0.07735
-0.077955
-71
-0.07681249
0.07727
-0.0775229
0.07733
-0.07747896
0.07738
-0.07714205
0.07746
-0.07737642
0.07744
-0.07761809
0.07727
-0.07755951
0.07754
-0.07792571

Option Explicit
Public Type RUN_Type
RUN_STRUCT() As Variant
End Type

Public Type SECTION_Type
SECTION_STRUCT() As RUN_Type
End Type

Sub actual2()



Dim surface As String, Section As String, run As String
Dim DATA() As Variant, counter_surf  As Long, counter_sect As Long
Dim counter_run As Long
Dim SURFACE_STRUCT() As SECTION_Type, n As Long, m As Long
Dim counter As Integer
Dim Endoffileflag As Boolean, errorflag As Boolean



surface = "SURFACE"
Section = "SECTION"
run = "RUN"
counter = 0
counter_surf = 0
counter_sect = 0
counter_run = 0
Endoffileflag = False
errorflag = False



 Do While counter <= UBound(DATA) And Endoffileflag = False
 If Endoffileflag = False Then
 errorflag = True
 End If
 Do While DATA(counter) = surface And Endofflileflag = False

    ReDim Preserve SURFACE_STRUCT(counter_surf)
    If counter < UBound(DATA) Then
    errorflag = True
    End If

        Do While DATA(counter) = Section And Endofflileflag = False
            ReDim Preserve SECTION_STRUCT(counter_sect)
            If counter < UBound(DATA) Then
            errorflag = True
            End If

            Do While DATA(counter) = run And Endofflileflag = False
            ReDim Preserve RUN_STRUCT(counter_run)
            If counter < UBound(DATA) And IsNumeric(DATA(counter)) Then
            errorflag = True
            SURFACE_STRUCT(counter_surf).SECTION_STRUCT(counter_sect).,
            RUN_STRUCT(counter_run) = (DATA(counter))
            End If
            counter_run = counter_run + 1

        Loop
            counter_sect = counter_sect + 1
        Loop
    counter_surf = counter_surf + 1
 Loop

counter = counter + 1
Loop

Close #2
End Sub
Thank you.
```

Comment: StackOverflow doesnt encourage entire code written without some attempt, or starting point. Look into class modules. You could create a class called surface, and one called section. Surfaces then contain sections, and they can in turn contain 'run' properties.

Comment: Please, MacroMarc, this is there code I have this far to parse the data posted above into hierarchical order of surface, section, run. It is not working and if you guide me to achieve my purpose I will be glad. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I don't know if you still need this but, you could do this just as easily with a type since your objects aren't really doing anything apart from storing data.

Just an example of how it could work:

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public Type RUN_Type
  Values() As Double
End Type

Public Type SECTION_Type
  Runs() As RUN_Type
End Type

Public Type SURFACE_Type
 Sections() As SECTION_Type
End Type

Sub actual2()
  Const surface = "SURFACE"
  Const section = "SECTION"
  Const run = "RUN"

  Dim DATA() As Variant, surfaces() As SURFACE_Type
  Dim counter As Long, counter_surf  As Long, counter_sect As Long, counter_run As Long, counter_num As Long

  counter = 1
  DATA = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(86, 1)).Value

  Do While DATA(counter, 1) = surface
        incr counter_surf
        ReDim Preserve surfaces(counter_surf)
        incr counter
        If counter > UBound(DATA) Then
              endRead surfaces
              Exit Sub
        End If
        Do While DATA(counter, 1) = section
              incr counter_sect
              ReDim Preserve surfaces(counter_surf).Sections(counter_sect)
              incr counter
              If counter > UBound(DATA) Then
                    endRead surfaces
                    Exit Sub
              End If
              Do While DATA(counter, 1) = run
                    incr counter_run
                    ReDim Preserve surfaces(counter_surf).Sections(counter_sect).Runs(counter_run)
                    incr counter
                    If counter > UBound(DATA) Then
                                endRead surfaces
                          Exit Sub
                    End If
                    Do While IsNumeric(DATA(counter, 1))
                          incr counter_num
                          ReDim Preserve surfaces(counter_surf).Sections(counter_sect).Runs(counter_run).Values(counter_num)
                          surfaces(counter_surf).Sections(counter_sect).Runs(counter_run).Values(counter_num) = DATA(counter, 1)
                          incr counter
                          If counter > UBound(DATA) Then
                                endRead surfaces
                                Exit Sub
                          End If
                    Loop
                    counter_num = 0
              Loop
              counter_run = 0
        Loop
        counter_sect = 0
  Loop
End Sub

Public Sub endRead(surfaces() As SURFACE_Type)

  Const surface = "SURFACE"
  Const section = "SECTION"
  Const run = "RUN"

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim counter As Long, i As Long, j As Long, k As Long, l As Long

  Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
  counter = 1

  For i = LBound(surfaces) To UBound(surfaces)
        ws.Cells(counter, 2).Value = surface
        incr counter
        For j = LBound(surfaces(i).Sections) To UBound(surfaces(i).Sections)
              ws.Cells(counter, 3).Value = section
              incr counter
              For k = LBound(surfaces(i).Sections(j).Runs) To UBound(surfaces(i).Sections(j).Runs)
                    ws.Cells(counter, 4).Value = run
                    incr counter
                    For l = LBound(surfaces(i).Sections(j).Runs(k).Values) To UBound(surfaces(i).Sections(j).Runs(k).Values)
                          ws.Cells(counter, 5).Value = surfaces(i).Sections(j).Runs(k).Values(l)
                          incr counter
                    Next l
              Next k
        Next j
  Next i

End Sub

 Public Function incr(lng As Long)
    lng = lng + 1
End Function
```